# I can only slice my pandas dataframe with a slicing window such as [0:1] to get a specific row, doing [0 raises a KeyError why?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`.

```
type(df) # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df[0] # KeyError 0

df[0:1] # Gives row 0 as expected
```

What is going on? I am sorry I come from an R background and have done some work with Python in the past but thought this was possible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! If you use .iloc it will return what you are expecting. So for this case you would be

```
first_row = df.iloc[0]
```

When you do `df[0]` it is looking for a column named 0.

reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: The nice thing about iloc is you can also select specific columns. More details in the link! Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw, when I slice and say `df[0:4]`, why does it not look for columns then?